# Writing multiple files Vs. writing one big file [in a solid state drive]

Tags: windows, image, performance, filesystems

(I was not able to find a clear answer to my question, maybe I used the wrong search term)

I want to record many images from a camera, with no compression or lossless compression, on a not so powerful device with one single solid drive.
After investigating, I have decided that, if any, the compression will be simply png image by image (this is not part of the discussion).
Given these constraints, I want to be able to record at maximum possible frequency from the camera. The bottleneck is the (only one) hard drive speed. I want to use the RAM for queuing, and the few available cores for compressing the images in parallel, so that there's less data to write.

Once the data is compressed, do I get any gain in writing speed if I stream all the bytes in one single file, or, considering that I am working with a solid drive, can I just write one file (let's say about 1 or 2 MB) per image still working at the maximum disk bandwidth? (or very close to it, like >90%)?

I don't know if it matters, this will be done using C++ and its libraries.

Comment: Setting realistic project goals is essential and there's very little evidence that you got there yet.  That really does need to start by you finding out what the device is capable of.  From there you'll know what's possible, this just can't work the other way around.  It is almost inevitable that you'll find out that you have to de-tune the no-compression requirement or put up with a glacial shot rate.

Comment: @HansPassant Loss-less compression is the only option for this kind of job. Loss-less compression codec that work well for grayscale images are nearly impossible to find. I can live with relatively low frame rate, I am anyway trying to get the best possible. My question is "simply" if by writing my output on a single file instead of in many 2MB files I can expect a significant benefit, when working with a solid state drive. I will probably try at some point, but I was trying to understand if anybody had experience about this.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that the SSD should be a bottle neck. How many images per second are we talking about? If I/O performance is an issue I would not use C++ libraries but Windows API with Overlapped I/O.

Comment: @WernerHenze We are speaking about pretty high resolution images. Thanks for the hint about the Windows API with Overlapped I/O

Answer (score 7):

> My question is "simply" if by writing my output on a single file instead of in many 2MB files I can expect a significant benefit, when working with a solid state drive.

There's a benefit, not a significant one.  A file system driver for a solid state drive already knows how to distribute the data of a file across many non-adjacent clusters so doing it yourself doesn't help.  Necessary to fit a large file on a drive that already contains files.  By breaking it up, you force *extra* writes to also add the directory entries for those segments.

The type of a solid state drive matters but this is in general already done by the driver to implement "wear-leveling".  In other words, *intentionally* scatter the data across the drive.  This avoids wearing out flash memory cells, they have a limited number of times you can write them before they physically wear out and fail.  Traditionally only guaranteed at 10,000 writes, they've gotten better.  You'll exercise this of course.  Notable as well is that flash drives are fast to read but slow to write, that matters in your case.

There's one notable advantage to breaking up the image data into separate files: it is easier to recover from a drive error.  Either from a disastrous failure or the drive just filling up to capacity without you stopping in time.  You don't lose the entire shot.  But inconvenient to whatever program reads the images off the drive, it has to glue them back together.  Which is an important design goal as well, if you make it too impractical with a non-standard uncompressed file format or just too slow to transfer or just too inconvenient in general then it will just not get used very often.

Comment: I wonder how much the extra writes to update the filesystem have an impact... It sounds pretty inefficient, but again here I don't know enough how the filesystem handles the update of the directory contents. If the chunks in which the data is scattered into the drive are small enough than it would be just one write within many writes, it would be interesting to know the typical size of these chunks

Comment: I don't understand why you won't just write a little test program that writes a big file and run it on the device.  Now you *know* instead of having to rely on guesses from SO users that don't know the actual hardware you are using.

Comment: I was trying to see if anybody had had experience with this kind of problem/choice (I thought it could be a quite standard problem, but surprisingly google didn't give any helpful results), and I do not have access yet to the exact hardware I will have to use at this moment, while the software has to be ready as much as possible in advance.

Comment: @HansPassant, Re " they've gotten better", how much better? 2x or 10x?